# JPA One entity for Two Tables without SecondaryTable

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I describe some ECM domain model that constists of Folders and Documents.
To put it very simply, folders can contain documents and other folders (subfolders). Both folders and documents have attributes. Attributes can be of different types.

In OOP, this model is described by [the following diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTwI4.png)

And I need to map this structure to database tables.

My problem comes in when I try to map `Attr` entity to the table in database.
`Attr` have **many-to-one** relationship with `Document` and with `Folder` entities.
It means that table `ATTR` must have two foreign keys: `DOCUMENT_FK` and `FOLDER_FK` respectively.

Therefore ER diagram would look [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tezLa.png)

And corresponding JPA mapping:

```java
package ru.max.db.folders.domain

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTR_TYPE")
class AttrType(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long,
    val name: String
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "ATTR")
class Attr(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE")
    val type: AttrType,
    val value: String
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
class Document(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long,
    val type: String,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_FOLDER")
    val parentFolder: Folder,
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_ID")
    val attrs: MutableList<Attr>?
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDER")
class Folder(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long,
    val clazz: String,
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOLDER_ID")
    val attrs: MutableList<Attr>?,
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_FOLDER")
    val subFolders: MutableList<Folder>?,
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_FOLDER")
    val documents: MutableList<Document>?
)
```

The problem with this solution is that `ATTR.FOLDER_ID` and `ATTR.DOCUMENT_ID` foreign keys columns must be nullable and some rows would point to folders' attributes while another - to documents' attributes. That doesn't look well for me.

What I want is to split `ATTR` into two different tables `FOLDER_ATTR` and `DOCUMENT_ATTR`. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqUze.png) is corresponding ER diagram:

But `FOLDER_ATTR` has the same structure as `DOCUMENT_ATTR`. Therefore it can be represented with one JPA entity. But how can I descibe this mapping with JPA annotations (or, maybe with .xml)?

Of course **I can't** use two `@Table` annotations on `Attr` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT_ATTR")
@Table(name = "FOLDER_ATTR")
class Attr(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE")
    val type: AttrType,
    val value: String
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
class Document(
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID")
    val attrs: MutableList<Attr>?
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDER")
class Folder(
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID")
    val attrs: MutableList<Attr>?,
    ...
)
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want here somehow? I don't want to have two different classes representing the same structure just to fit into database model.

Answer (score 0):

you could keep the object model as is, and instead of using two foreign key on ATTR table you could use two join table (DOCUMENT_ATTR, FOLDER_ATTR) if this make more sense for you

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
class Document(
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(
       name = "DOCUMENT_ATTR",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="document_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="attr_id")
    )
    val attrs: MutableList<Attr>?
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDER")
class Folder(
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
       name = "FOLDER_ATTR",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="folder_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="attr_id")
    )
    val attrs: MutableList<Attr>?,
    ...
)
```